# Event unsubscription memory leak due to exception

Tags: .net, events, exception, memory-leaks

I didn't want to go through all the event unsubscription memory leak posts to see if any dealt with exceptions, so I'm making a new post.

If I register a function with an event and an exception occurs before I unregister, will that cause a memory leak?  I have a try/catch in the calling function, but not in the function where I wire/unwire the event, and would rather not have a try/catch if I don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With most subscription methods, an event subscriber who does not unsubscribe will have his lifetime extended to that of the event source.  If the event source is short-lived, this will not be a problem.  If the event source is long-lived, this can be a huge problem.  The best idiom is generally to unwire events in IDisposable.  If one uses a "using" block, the Dispose method will get called, ensuring the events get unsubscribed.